# Crop text image within background using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I would like to extract the letter from the blue images shown below.

Ideally, the result would be a cropped black letter image on a white background as shown below.

There may be functions of CV that would enable me to go this effectively.
I think this would be a more simple thing to do if the original letters weren't white. It would be more simple to crop the image to the extent of the letter and change the font color to black.

Appreciate any help.

### Image example 1

### [image: Image 1]

### Image example 2

### [image: Image 2]

### Result

### [image: Image 3]

---

Comment: first, locate/isolate the shape. show how you do that. -- changing white-on-blue to black-on-white will be trivial. it's just a little bit of math. for the specific case of blue, just take the red or green channel and invert it.

Comment: For the case of the image with C I would create a bounding box to the extent of the rhombus shape. There would remain a white border around the letter. Since the white border and letter are the same color, there would be no way to discern between the two.